# Can a call to np.array without the dtype argument raise an error?

Tags: python, numpy

Can the following call raise an error for any value of `x`:

```
arr = np.array(x, copy=False, subok=False)
```

I have tried a bunch of different inputs that I though might be invalid, but the worst I got was a scalar array with `dtype=object`.

I do understand that setting the `dtype` argument will easily get me a `TypeError`.

Comment: It could raise a `MemoryError`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. It could also raise a KeyBoardInterrupt or whatever it's called at that point :)

Comment: Surprisingly, `lst = []; lst.append(lst); arr = np.array(lst)` doesn't raise an exception; it gives you a 32D array whose sole element is a reference to `lst`.

Comment: What does `np.array` do with a C extension type that supports the sequence API or the buffer API but raises an exception when you try to call it?

Comment: @abarnert, `np.ndarray` might be a better constructor when using something with the buffer API.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure, but we're not looking for the "better" constructor here, we're looking for the one that we can trick into throwing an exception. I believe `array` does look for `bf.getbuffer` (see `np.array(memoryview(b'abc'))` for example—you don't get a single `|S3` element as with `b'abc'` used directly, or an `object`, you get 3 `uint8`s).

Comment: @abarnert that is wicked!

Comment: @Davidmh I just realized you can do the same thing with a finitely-nested list whose max depth is >32, so it's not as exciting anymore that it also works for an infinitely-nested list. The element is a nested list that's depth(x)-32 deep, and aleph-null - 32 = aleph-null, so there's nothing inconsistent here…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup.

```
>>> numpy.array([1, [2]], copy=False, subok=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Tested on NumPy version 1.14.2, in case it matters.

Comment: I'm very surprised that that does not turn into `dtype=object`. Might have to ask about that on the mailing list...

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, especially since `np.array([[1], 2], copy=False, subok=False)` does *not* raise an error.  It gives you the `object` array that you expected.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. For reference, I asked on the list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2018-April/077901.html

Comment: @MadPhysicist We've noted this behavior on SO for quite some time.  Evidently it tries, based on the initial entry to create a numeric array.  But when it encounters a list with deeper nesting, it raises this error.  Do we want it to backtrack and start over with `object` dtype?  Some have opined that `np.array` shouldn't make an `object` dtype unless you tell it to.  But even then it's tricky to make an array of equal length objects or subarrays.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to just pass it an object that acts enough like a sequence to get `array` to treat it as one, but then throw it off the trail once it starts. I can't remember the exact rules for what `array` considers a sequence, but it's still pretty easy to find things that break.

---

For example, confuse it into building a size-2 array before realizing that (by the old-style sequence iterator protocol) the object actually has length 0:

```
class BadSeq:
    def __len__(self):
        return 2
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        raise IndexError()
```

Now `np.array(BadSeq())` will raise:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 0
```

By contrast, `list(BadSeq())` will return an empty list.

---

Or just violate the sequence protocol entirely:

```
class BadSeq:
    def __len__(self):
        return 2
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        raise TypeError(f"Take your {type(idx).__name__} and shove it")
```

Now `np.array(BadSeq())` will just pass the `TypeError` through:

```
TypeError: Take your int and shove it
```

Of course here, `list` has the same behavior.

---

I believe you can play similar tricks with the buffer protocol, but that requires building a C extension, which is more work than I want to put into this. (Actually, I did try hacking up a `memoryview` from an `array.array` via `ctypes.pythonapi`, but it turns out that segfaults are easier to get than exceptions that way, and if that's what you want, there are better ways to do it…)

---

As a side note, the following code does *not* raise an exception, but probably doesn't do what you want:

```
x = []
x.append(x)
arr = np.array(x, copy=False, subok=False)
```

The original `x` is an infinite-dimensional nested list, but `arr` is a 32D array whose single element (`arr[(1,)*32])`) is a reference to `x`, as an `object`. Although you get effectively the same result with finite nesting:

```
y = []
for _ in range(33): y = [y[:]]
arr = np.array(y, copy=False, subok=False)
```

This gives you a 32D array whose single element is a 3D nested list.

Comment: 32 is the maximum number of dimensions.  It is probably hardcoded at several places in the numpy source.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, that's pretty obvious from the behavior of `y`.

Comment: This answer is excellent, but when I wrote this question, I just wanted to know whether it would be worth checking for errors in a particular situation. Seems like it's easy enough to cause an error that it's worth checking, that simple. I don't want you to think that my selection of the other answer is in any way a reflection of my opinion on your answer's quality.